# Cube Processing fails only in parallel mode

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing, sql-server-2012, ssas, cube

i do have a somewhat reproducable error, which i am no longer willing to bear, so i hope some of you might know a better workaround.

I have several larger cubes (around 10-50 GByte) which i process daily. The processing of only the partitions (about 20%) takes about 1h when i use  in XMLA-Script - so processing dimensions and measures in paralellel-mode.
This works in only 2/5 runs.

So i have a procedure which detects the crash and if happened starts the serial-processing instead, which will run about 2-5 times slower - but at least works every time.

The error codes are very generic and not very helpful:

- Operation canceled; HY008
- Communication link failure; 08S01; TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

And since it works every time in serial mode i know that there are no errors in principle.

I am using 
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
Enterprise Edition: Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600:)

Please, if you have any ideas how to solve (workaround) this.

I am thankful for every new insight or idea you might have to this behaviour.

Comment: Please also specify server cores amount, server timeout parameters, 'CoordinatorExecutionMode' and 'ThreadPool\Process\MaxThreads', and DB parameter 'Maximum Number of Connections'.

Comment: Gladly (thanx for bothering):  
cores amount:   
::`6 Cores (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 v2 @ 2,20 GHz)`  
::`(So the SQL-Server believes it has 12 cores)`  
::The Maximum-Worker Threads are set to `0 (unlimited)`  
::  
server timeout parameters:  
:: `Remote Query timeout (in seconds) 600`  
:: Parallelism :: `Query Wait = -1`  
:: `Query Execution Timeout: 0 (no time-out)`  
::   
`CoordinatorExecutionMode: -4`  
::  
`ThreadPool\Process\MaxThreads: 0`  
::  
DB parameter `Maximum Number of Connections: 0 (unlimited)`  

(sorry for missing linebreaks)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like concurrency issue and/or heavy SQL server workload (e.g. caused by mostly unlimited threads from SSAS server). I guess, it's better to set up MAX-values for necessary parameters:

ThreadPool\Process\MaxThreads = 4*cores

DB Number of Connections = 2*cores-1 (it's based on my own practice). You can tune this right before and after processing task if it's necessary to have huge amount of connections not in process time.

And maybe somehow play with affinity masks, but previous parameters tuning should be enough.

This article
http://phoebix.com/2014/07/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-ssas-processor-affinity/
and this book
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh226085.aspx
describe whole technique in details.

**UPDATE:**

There is also small possibility of wrong TCP settings, described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cindygross/archive/2009/10/22/sql-server-and-tcp-chimney.aspx

But this may cause fails even in serial processing.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you very much.

It is my experience too. The less parallelism i allow the more reliable the SSIS/SSAS is.

I will try these calculations and come back here and comment.

Comment: Setting limit on ThreadPool\Process\MaxThreads helped in my case. This should be marked as answer.